# How to connect to Sybase(BPPM tool) database using SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, sybase

I have a requirement of pulling data from sybase database to SQL using an SSIS package. I cannot find any provider/sybase connector till now. Searched a lot on google/tried multiple suggestions but picture is not clear anywhere.
Kindly let me know what is the step by step process and download link of driver if required. I would prefer if it can be done without any new installation as it would require more approvals from client.

Comment: What exactly is the sybase product and version?

Comment: Thanks Nick for taking time to read my question. I got to know that its a BPPM tool with default sybase database installed, and all the data from BPPM goes to sybase database. Let me know what all factors needs to be taken into consideration before suggesting anything to client.

Comment: Googling BBPM.. it might be Sybase IQ. You need to find out the version of sybase then install the appropriate client libraries /  ODBC driver on your SQL Server and dev machine. It might be easiest to remote on the the source machine and see whats in the ODBC manager. Is your client paying to ask questions on SO, for which in turn I am simply googling to find the correct answer? That doesn't seem like very good value for money

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install ASE from SAP website, then using ODBC connector, we can connect to sybase database in SSIS.